# Winform C#, close form on click button from other computers in one project

Tags: c#, webforms

i've develop a web application , i've develop a caller id system which runs on multiple system with using same sql server database , what i want to do is when callerid form appear on all pc and one of them click make booking button all other pc caller id form will close

Answer (score 0):

you need a Server in your system 
and you can use socket or SignalR to trigger the event on other apps

but i think you have a  architecter problem .

your application (normaly) need to communicat  with present of a one part ( a Server ) who can throw SQL Data as a Webservice for example .